# How to set priority for hadoop job in java code while triggering it?

Tags: java, hadoop

this is how my jobrunner looks. How can I set low priority while triggering this job itself ?

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    this.initJob();
    Path outputPath = new Path(args[2]);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, args[0]);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

    job.getConfiguration().set("FREQUENCY", args[3]);
    job.getConfiguration().set("TIMEZONE", args[4]);

    boolean rc = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (rc) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
public void initJob() throws IOException {
    job = new Job(getConf(), "Stats Data Cruncher");
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);       
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
    Job.setInputFormatClass(LzoTextInputFormat.class);  

    job.setJarByClass(JobRunner.class);
    job.setMapperClass(StatsMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(StatsCombiner.class);        
    job.setReducerClass(StatsReducer.class);
}
```

is this line valid to set LOW priority ?

```
job.getConfiguration().set("PRIORITY", "LOW");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"mapred.job.priority" is the property you are looking for.

You can set this in your configuration like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
// set the priority to VERY_HIGH
conf.set("mapred.job.priority", JobPriority.VERY_HIGH.toString());
```

Comment: Any idea where this priority is read and how it is passed to the scheduler?

Answer (score 5):

Three methods you can use to set your job priority:

1. Set user's job priority in xml config file.
2. Set your job using Hadoop command as bellow:

   hadoop job -set-priority
3. in java code,you can set job priority in configuration:

   conf.set("mapred.job.priority", JOBPRIORITY.toString());

The value of JOBPRIORITY may be:

JobPriority.VERY_HIGH

JobPriority.HIGH

JobPriority.NORMAL

JobPriority.LOW

JobPriority.VERY_LOW